# Android Xamarin App content

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing some small android app using visual studio and xamarin on C#.
Application is simple for beggining, it has 3 menu items (profile, news feed, images), and i want to switch app content on menu item click.
2 approaches that i tried was creating 3 differen layouts for each of menu items, than switching them with SetContentView, and 2nd approact was creating 3 Activities each using SetContentView for every layout.

As a new developer on xamarain and generaly for android devices i am not sure about is any of these 2 methods good way to do this.

Can anyone recomend best approach for this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either create separate activities or fragments for each screen you want to display. If you use activities, then you should start them with an `Intent`. For fragments, you should use the `FragmentManager` to switch fragments. There are several tutorials online about these techniques. Most of them are in Java, but you should be able to translate fairly easy.

Comment: thanks, but what would u reccomend me for my situtatio? Activities or FragmentMenager?

Comment: @user2200319 You should learn about both and determine for yourself which works better for you.